# Search text using #hashtag and scroll in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have loaded text in a `UIWebView`. Each sentence is under the anchor `<a>` tag. The `<a>` tag's `href` attribute has the sentence number like `<a href = '#%d'>`. Now when the user search, the UIWebView should scroll up to the line or the `<a>` tag.

I used some js code but it doesn't work.

1.

```
NSString *jscript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.location.href = '%d';", self.selectedIndex];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jscript];
```

2.

```
NSString *jscript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.location=\"myapp#%d\";", self.selectedIndex];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jscript];
```

3.I was trying to use this but couldn't implement

```
NSString *jscript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$(document).ready(function() { %d;}", self.selectedIndex];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jscript];
```

I have negligible knowledge of javascript, may be that is why I am not able to understand where I am going wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you help me to use the answer in to swift/objc code. I am trying `let script  = "var el = document.getElementById('id_of_the_element'); window.onload = function () { window.scrollTo(20,el.offsetTop); } "
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: nil)` but not working from my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll to position by simply writing few lines of `javascript` . If you want to scroll to that position at the page load you can use

```
<script> 
var el = document.getElementById("id_of_the_element"); 
window.onload = function () { 
window.scrollTo(20,el.offsetTop); 
} </script>
```

Comment: Yippee...I worked. Thank very much. You are my hero. :)

Comment: Can you help me to use the answer in to swift/objc code. I am trying `let script  = "var el = document.getElementById('id_of_the_element'); window.onload = function () { window.scrollTo(20,el.offsetTop); } "
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: nil)` but not working from my side